# Receive values in request helper as integer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a form with a `select` tag that I am sending data into my laravel blade like below :

```
 <form action="{{ route('shop.products.index', $product->url_key) }}" method="get">
                        <select style=" font-family: IranSansLight, sans-serif; width:100%" class="mdb-select md-form" name="color_id">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" value="send">
                    </form>
```

and I receive it in the same page as below :

```
request()->get('color_id')
```

The problem is this is receiving the data as string but I need the values to be an integer, so how can I get the integer or convert them to integer?

Comment: its in blade can i use that ?? i am using the request helper

Comment: You can add integer rule for your request (I hope you have custom request class for incoming data to control it) or just put `(int)` before your `request()->get('color_id')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$colorId = (int)request()->get('color_id');
```

OR

```
$colorId = intval(request()->get('color_id'))
```